# Is it correct behaviour for a client to trim the port when following HTTP 302

Tags: http, redirect, https, http-status-code-302

Is it correct behaviour for an HTTP client to trim the :443 port from a 302 redirect?

I notice that web browsers do this. So, if redirected to https://website.domain.com:443 they actually subsequently request https://website.domain.com. I coudln't find a clear answer in the standard.

I am writing an iOS App that is interacting with an HTTP authentication server that is explicitly adding :443 to a 302 redirect. My app follows the redirect verbatim, but unfortunately this makes the SSO Login server reject the authentication attempt because it's performing hostname verification.

It deems login.domain.com:443 to be different from login.domain.com.

The flow is:

1. Request https://website.domain.com/protected_page
2. Am redirected to https://login.domain.com
3. login.domain.com redirects to https://login.domain.com:443/auth

   1. At this point a browser would redirect to https://login.domain.com/auth
   2. My App redirects verbatim to https://login.domain.com:443/auth

Is my App's behaviour correct?

Is the login server's assertion that login.domain.com:443 is not the same domain as login.domain.com correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have come across a design fault in the login server.

[RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), section 3.2.3 states that

> URI producers and normalizers should omit the port component and
>   its ":" delimiter if port is empty or if its value would be the
>   same as that of the scheme's default.

I.e. any URI parser should realize that if the port is omitted, default value of the port must be used, consequently https://login.domain.com and https://login.domain.com:443 are the same URI component.

What you can do is alter the URI if this is needed for login server to accept it.